# Change mouse-pointer in revolution slider

Tags: css, wordpress, html, revolution-slider

I am currently working on this [WordPres-Template](http://medikal.victheme.com/). Do you see the button under "Make an appointment"? I somehow need to change the mouse-pointer onmouseover to the default values. But the template uses Revolution Slider, so I have no idea where to put the code in.

I tried something like this:

```css
img:hover
{
    cursor:ponter;
}
```

[GUI of Revolution Slider](http://oi67.tinypic.com/111mgiq.jpg)

I also tried this:

```css
.tp-caption .lfr .tp-scrollbelowslider .start .img:hover
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

The HTML of the slider looks like this:

```html
<div class="tp-caption lfr tp-scrollbelowslider start" data-x="703" data-y="691" data-speed="300" data-start="500" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-endspeed="300" data-scrolloffset="0" style="z-index: 9; left: 0px; top: 200px; visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><img style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" src="http://test.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/whitebutton.png" alt=""> 
        </div>
<img style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" src="http://test.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/whitebutton.png" alt="">
```

This selector also doesn't work:

```css
li.tp-revslider-slidesli:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(6) > img:nth-child(1):hover
```

Comment: Please add the code directly into your question, there is no need to use an image. Nobody wants to have to type the code into an answer when copy&paste is so much easier.

Comment: To increase the priority of a CSS directive make it more precise. Instead of  `img:hover` us `body article .div-a .div-b img:hover`. The more precise the dom path is, the higher the priority gets when it is rendered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You dont need javascript , you can do it by css Go to your css file and paste this line and it will work: `.start{cursor:pointer!important;}`

Comment: Yes, this works but than I have the mouse-pointer on the complete left side (the blue box with the text in it). I think, my problem is, that I am not able to find the correct selector. Last try was: 

.tp-caption .lfr .tp-scrollbelowslider .start .img:hover

Comment: then you need to use it like this:  .start img {cursor:pointer!important;}

Comment: I tried it already. 

.start img:hover
{
  cursor:pointer !important;
}

works fine, but the blue box is also a img, and so you have the problem again. 

My CSS is not very well. I think all I need is the correct syntax to select **only** this class="tp-caption lfr tp-scrollbelowslider start" and I'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`cursor:pointer!important;` will do the job if you enter it for the selected layer, under the **Style -> Advanced CSS** option of that specific layer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Wish this was the accepted answer.